# how to remove unwanted data from a file created using writeobject in android

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am a newbie in android/java, actually c++ programmer.  In my android project, i want to write some structured data into a file and read back by using a C++ program.  But the written data file contains structured data with some unwanted data.  How to avoid unwanted data while writing to file.  I am also pasting code for my program, program contains no error, just for reference

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestAppActivity extends Activity implements Serializable {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
    Example example = new Example();
    example.number = 50;
    example.name = "Test_Value";

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"/text.dat"));
        out.writeObject((Example) example);
        out.close();

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), "") + "/text.dat"));
        Example readed = (Example)in.readObject();
        in.close();
        Log.e("Received", readed.number + " " + readed.name );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("__ERROR__", e.toString());           
    }
}

class Example implements Serializable {
    public int number;
    public String name;
}
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What "unwanted data" are you referring to? And why don't you use plain text or xml or something to read and write?

Comment: unwanted data contain class name, some codes etc.  In C++, easy way to write contains of a structure to file using file.write function, Is any equivalent method in android.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectOutputStream writes your object in a [specific format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) so it can be read later by other Java programs. If you would like control over the way data is written to a file you'd better not use ObjectOutputStream and serialize the data yourself, e.g. as xml or json.

Alternatively you could let your object implement the [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface but this requires you to implement both the `readExternal` and `writeExternal` methods, so you still end up serializing the object yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some custom serialisation, depending on desired format.  Binary format would be pretty tricky due to potential issues with endianness  etc.  For this you can use NIO byte buffers:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

You can tune endianness there and store binary values at predefined offsets.

In case text based format are acceptable, I would recommend JSON data binding:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer

It's jst as easy as this:

```
JSONMarshaller.marshall(<outputStremWriterYouHaveToCreate>,<objectToSerialize>)
```

will marshall object ( also object tree, array ) to JSON  data stream